# Show ios push notification for long time on phone screen

Tags: ios, push-notification

Is there any way to show a particular type(some important) of push notification for some 5-10 seconds on the iOS device screen when app is in background.

Answer (score 2):

**No, the time is fixed**.

You cannot customize it - a push-notification should be a short message that in the best case makes the user tap it and open the app. There is actually not really a need for a longer time. Keep it short, simple and interesting and the user will react accordingly anyway. A longer time should not really make any difference other than people getting annoyed because your messages are always staying on top, blocking other messages and wasting screen space.